# Horizontal Index Match: Find Text In A Matrix And Return The Header

Tags: excel, find, match, excel-2010

I have a list of names. I also have a matrix containing the names and their corresponding auditor as the column heading. I need to lookup the name in this matrix and once the name is found, I need to get the auditor which is the column heading. I have a code that works vertically but i can't find the formula to make it work horizontally.

[image]

This is my working code for the vertical matrix:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(auditors,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(names=A106),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(names)^0)),0)),"")
```

Comment: Can you give us a visual representation of the data?

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner i just added an image to my post... Thank you so much for checking out my question!

Comment: You might want to combine `INDEX` and `MATCH`. P.e: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:C4,1,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A2:C4,0))`

Comment: This may help: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/07/09/search-for-a-text-string-in-an-excel-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(auditors,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(names)-MIN(COLUMN(names))+1)/(names=H2),1)),"")
```

Assuming your first Header is in A1.  Put that formula in A2 and copy over and down.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Scott, i tried it and returned a different result.

Comment: Hello @Scott, i tried it and returned the following result:
`Assigned To    Auditor
Name 1           Auditor 1
Name 2           Auditor 1
Name 3           Auditor 1
Name 4           Auditor 1
Name 5           Auditor 1
Name 6           Auditor 2
Name 7           Auditor 1`

Comment: @VeeEss sorry forgot to add `1` to the row.  see edit.

Comment: Im so sorry Scott if my question was confusing... The lookup array is the one with the Auditor Headings A1:C4, and the formula should be in cell J2 in your screencap.

Comment: Hello @Scott, your formula is the answer. So far, this is the only working formula. Thank you so much. I now have something to present to my boss. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using this as an array formula seems to do the trick quite well:

`{=INDEX(Auditors;1;SUM(IF(Names=Auditors;COLUMN(Auditors);0)))}`

This works by creating a matrix the same size of your table where the cells contain either 0 or the column of the cell if there is a match. Note that it assumes your Auditor defined range starts at column 1 and includes the headers and the data (I used $A$1:$C$4)

Also, this will return Auditor 1 by default if there is no match; to force an error you can use the fact that the SUM result will be zero, for example like this:

`{=INDEX(Auditors;1;1/(1/SUM(IF(Names=Auditors;COLUMN(Auditors);0))))}`

Also, since it looks in the whole Auditors table, it will also match auditors themselves; if that's not what you want, you may want to define separate ranges for the header and the data of your auditor tables, or OFFSET them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are reasons to not want an array formula. Here is an example using a regular old `SUMPRODUCT`.

```
=INDEX(header_row,SUMPRODUCT((names=specific_name)*(COLUMN(header_row)-COLUMN(header_row_first_cell)+1)))
```

All cells/ranges should be fixed except for specific_name.

- header_row is 1 by 3 range from Auditor 1 through Auditor 3
- names is the 3 by 3 range of names in the matrix
- specific_name is the single cell with a name you are finding
- header_row_first_cell is the first cell in the header_row, so Auditor    1

Also, instead of the `COLUMN(header_row)-COLUMN(header_row_first_cell)+1` nonsense, I usually like to index my rows and columns. So above the header, I will number the columns 1 through 3 and simple use that range.

```
=INDEX(header_row,SUMPRODUCT((names=specific_name)*(column_index)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Adam for taking the time to answer my question.